Integrating Azure B2C custom sign up policy with MAUI app and creating new user in stream
Hello from a new novice developer. Thanks in advance for any helpful links, posts, guidance, etc..
Here's what I'm attempting to accomplish..

I am writing a .NET MAUI app and looking to integrated Stream Chat into the experience. I'm currently working on the user sign up, in, profile management, etc.. experience.
I have stream setup and working in dev mode, without "Disable Auth Check" enabled.
I have an Azure B2C environment setup and working using XML based custom policies..
Putting Azure aside for a second, I can hard code user details in C# to connect, view channels, post, see responses, etc..

I am setting up the user experience thus far in a way that when a new user decides to create an account in the MAUI, I hit Azure AD B2C, walk them through the sign up process and not only create the user in B2C with needed claim information for their identity management experience but then also create that user in Stream Chat utilizing the claims.
Here's what I have done..

Sign up process and B2C custom user journey works as expected.
I receive the claims and transform into a JSON body that, then as part of the B2C user journey and custom policy, transform the claims and generate a body for a request to Stream.
I then call an Azure Function from the B2C journey to POST to the function to act as a proxy and send the request to the stream api to create the user. This is due to B2C currently only supporting a single authorization header, while the stream api requires two.
The function successfully executes, calls Stream Chat to post to the API and the user journey continues successfully.
I can see the response as successful and also see the POST success in the Stream Chat Dashboard for the API call.

Here's where I'm scratching my head..

When I'm in the Stream Admin portal, I can't seem to see the newly created user anywhere in the dashboard? If I navigate to App / MyAppName / Chat Messaging / Explorer, I can see a list of test users that were created from templates and some that I manually created in the dashboard, but I don't see the users created from my flow..

I'm still very new to alot of this and super new to Stream Chat so any links, docs, suggestions, etc.. would be greatly appreciated. Happy to share anything that might help but I have success and green indicators all over just don't see the user in the dashboard so I can tweak, see the data I need to leverage/manipulate, etc...
Thanks in advance for reading all that if you have. Much appreciated!
-C

After a bit, I figured it out. I added a client initializer to the c# Azure function and leveraged the upsertUsers method to added the new user during a sign up B2C custom user journey.
Should anyone run into something similar, let me know and happy to share getting it all working together with B2C and might be useful elsewhere.
-C
